# iPhone swipe horizontally through tables

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

Okay, I'm hoping this will all make sense!

When you enter a view I would like for there to be 5 horizontal tables, one table visible at once (something like my rudimentary diagram below). You can then swipe to the left and the right, but instead of waiting for the gesture to complete and then transitioning, I would like for the user to be able to see it sliding as they scroll - so live scrolling, so to speak. Once it reaches, say, 50% to another table it would then complete the transition for you.

How would I start with making this? I know it's possible as it's in quite a few apps already - e.g., Spotify.

Thanks!

```
+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
|          |          |          |          |          |
|          |          | INITIAL  |          |          |
|          |          | SCREEN   |          |          |
|          |          |          |          |          |
|          |          |          |          |          |
|          |          |          |          |          |
|          |          |          |          |          |
|          |          |          |          |          |
+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
```

Comment: Before going for this approach, One point i would like to highlight is, if in future you need to implement swipe to remove cell from table than this swipe will conflict with `UITableView` swipe to remove cell.

Comment: @Kampai Yup, this is a point I bought up with our UI/X guy and he says it's fine. But good spot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `UIPageViewController`, and have each page be a table view controller.

Comment: Just to confirm, @LeoNatan, that `UIPageViewController` can do the "Live" scrolling? I think I tried before but it waited until the gesture finished and it then transitioned to the next screen?

Comment: No, it will ask your delegate for view controllers, and display their views as you scroll.